# How do sample weights work in classification models?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, weighted

What does it mean to provide weights to each sample for 
 classification? How does a classification algorithm like Logistic regression or SVMs use weights to emphasize certain examples more than others? I would love going into details to unpack how these algorithms leverage sample weights.

If you look at the sklearn [documentation for logistic regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit), you can see that the fit function has an optional sample_weight parameter which is defined as an array of weights assigned to individual samples.

Answer (score 6):

this option is meant for imbalance dataset. Let's take an example: i've got a lot of datas and some are just noise. But other are really important to me and i'd like my algorithm to consider them a lot more than the other points. So i assigne a weight to it in order to make sure that it will be dealt with properly.

It change the way the loss is calculate. The error (residues) will be multiplie by the weight of the point and thus, the minimum of the objective function will be shifted. I hope it's clear enough. i don't know if you're familiar with the math behind it so i provide here a small introduction to have everything under hand (apologize if this was not needed)
https://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/rgower/pdf/M2_statistique_optimisation/Intro-ML-expanded.pdf

Comment: Can you provide an example? Assume I've a imbalanced dataset where I have 100k positive data points and 20k negative data points. How much weight should I assign to make them balanced?

Answer (score 2):

See a good explanation here: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/11/machine-learning-what-why-how-weighting.html .